# Why by default Asp.Net Core references 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com'?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, cloudflare

I created an Asp.Net Core project by template (see image below).
The file "Pages/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml" has references to url "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com".
In our network environment it make problems to reference external resources so we have copied the files into the project.

I wonder why the default template provide code like that? Can someone explain me the advantages to reference cloudflare by an intranet only business 
application please? I'm a beginner with web developing so I wonder if that is best practice?

Many thanks for your effort!

Here is the template I used:

[image]

Comment: There is of course a benefit in using a CDN, they picked one. You can simply change it to a local address. The templates can't offer a perfect fit for every situation.

Comment: Did the template ask you whether this is an internal only business application and whether external resources are a problem? Then why would you expect them to know that's what you're creating it for? Keep in mind, these templates are for millions of people to consume, they may not meet specialized needs out of the box, so you may have to make adjustments. You might think they made the wrong default choice, but you'd have to take it up with them, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Clouflare (and other CDNs) help with page load speed

---

Cloudflare are a CDN (Content Delivery Network), which means that they can host things like common JavaScript and CSS files which are used by a large number of projects.

Whenever someone accesses your web application, their browser will have to go to your origin server (the server that the application is being served from). In most extranet cases, this can mean many hops from the user's machine to your server. But services like Cloudlfare, Akami, and Azure CDN (other CDNs) allow you host those files "on the edge". This is a fancy marketing term for "physically closer to the user".

(files can only be downloaded from a server at the speed of the slowest component, so placing them closer to the user means that they don't have to travel as far to get them)

Essentially these services have many hundreds of servers around the world which can host your files closer to your users, and usually, on faster server hardware than you might typically be able to afford. This means that page resources can be loaded into the browser much faster than if they were served from your single server - assuming that you only serve your web app from one server, in one data centre.

For intranet users, this may not represent a speed boost, and could actually represent a challenge as there might be firewall and security policies in place stopping someone from accessing a file hosted on a CDN. In this case, it would be common for the developer to download the resources (JS and CSS) and serve them as part of their app.

I would hazard a guess that Microsoft have included Cloudflare links to common libraries in their templates as the majority of developers will be hosting their applications either in the open, or on networks which allow access to CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

The template, foremost, is to serve as a demo application. In other words, they're doing things to show what is possible, and you're expected and encouraged to customize it to your own needs.

When it comes to this, the point is to show how to reference a resource from a CDN with a fallback to the local version of the resource, should that fail. It also shows off the use of the `environment` tag, to conditionally include/exclude HTML based on what environment its deployed to.

As far as `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` is concerned, the reasons are two-fold. First, it's a free, public CDN with a wide coverage of CSS and JS libraries, making it a good default pick. Second, it is what's used by LibMan, the default client-side library management system in ASP.NET Core. LibMan literally downloads the files from `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` to put them in the local `wwwroot/lib` directory.

As to why you'd want to use a CDN at all, it's all about edge delivery and caching. Your website will generally be located on one server in one location in the world. Even if you co-locate, you likely won't be using more than a handful of regions. CDN providers generally have servers all over the world, and the resources will be delivered to the user from the server that's closest to them, resulting in 50ms or less response times in most cases. Also, when it comes to common libraries like jQuery, Bootstrap, etc. if the user has *ever* visited a site on the internet that pulls those libraries from the CDN, they will already have the resources cached and will not need to download them again. CDNJS is one of the most popular CDNs out there for client-side libraries, so the odds are good that most if not all of the libraries your app depends on will have already be downloaded, resulting in faster load times for your site. If you serve something like jQuery locally, the user must download it all over again, even if they've already downloaded it 50 other times from 50 other sites.